# How to access a variable outside of a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, nested, global

this seems fairly simple but for some reason I can't understand it. I am trying to access and use a variable that has been defined within a function, but I want to use it **outside** of the function.

```
def eat_food():
    cheeseburger = 76
    banana = 12
    Honda = 198

def use_the_toilet():
    print(cheeseburger)
    banana += 1
    Honda = 1009

print(banana)
print(Honda)
```

Do I need to use global variables? If so, do I define them outside or inside the function? Does the following line of code change the way these variables could be accessed?

```
def eat_food():
    cheeseburger = 76
    banana = 12
    Honda = 198
    
    # Here I have defined a new variable within a function, within another function

    def use_the_toilet():
        print(cheeseburger)
        banana += 1
        Honda = 1009
        Rod_Stewart = 'gravy'

print(Rod_Stewart)
```

Comment: Why have `eat_food` in the first place? I think you're complicating things by forcing use of a function there. That functions doesn't do anything meaningful. You might as wall just have those variables where they're needed, then this becomes a non-problem. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to either make those variables global, or return them from the function (definitely prefer the latter though). However, I'd rethink the use of that function.

Comment: I just made this example up, I'm working on a bigger project that needs to use variables outside of the functions they are defined in. What do you mean by 'return them from the function'? Thank you.

Comment: Using the `return` statement within the function. You should read-up on `return` before you try to do anything else with functions. An understanding of `return` is pretty critical.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the return function, but not in the context of global variables